# Quadlet containers not starting on boot - problem with network-online.target?

Tags: systemd

I've created quadlets to launch two different containers in an opensuse environment (microOS, to be specific). The quadlets get planted in `/etc/containers/systemd` during an automated install. I expect them to run on the next boot (and every time thereafter).

Upon first boot, I see that the containers attempt to start but they both fail with the same error (*"Error: initializing source"*). It seems like the `network-online.target` isn't being honored. If I manually run `systemctl start`, both containers start up successfully.

Originally, the `WantedBy` line included `multi-user.target` and `default.target` but the latter appears unnecessary as I want the system to be fully up in order to deploy this container. The service is clearly being generated and is trying to start but the error makes it seem like it can't pull the image. I've reviewed the available `After` directives and `network-online.target` seems correct.

- `/etc/containers/systemd/wireguard.service:`

  ```ini
  [Unit]
  Description=Wireguard container
  After=network-online.target

  [Container]
  Image=docker.io/procustodibus/wireguard
  AddCapability=NET_ADMIN NET_RAW
  ContainerName=wireguard
  PublishPort=51822:51822/udp
  Volume=/etc/wireguard/conf:/etc/wireguard:Z
  PodmanArgs=--sysctl "net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1"

  [Install]
  # Start by default on boot
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Output of `systemctl status wireguard.service` after first boot:

  ```
  × wireguard.service - Wireguard container
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/containers/systemd/wireguard.container; generated)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-11-22 21:10:23 UTC; 5min ago
      Process: 1395 ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --name=wireguard --cidfile=/run/wireguard.cid --replace --rm --cgroups=split --sdnotify=conmon -d --cap-add=net_admin --cap-add=net_raw -v /etc/wireguard/conf:/etc/wireguard:Z --publish 51822:51822/udp --sysctl net.ipv4.co>
      Process: 1520 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/podman rm -f -i --cidfile=/run/wireguard.cid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 1395 (code=exited, status=125)
          CPU: 392ms

  Nov 22 21:10:20 proscale-micro-01.abc.abctechnology.com systemd[1]: Starting Wireguard container...
  Nov 22 21:10:23 proscale-micro-01.abc.abctechnology.com wireguard[1395]: Trying to pull docker.io/procustodibus/wireguard:latest...
  Nov 22 21:10:23 proscale-micro-01.abc.abctechnology.com wireguard[1395]: Pulling image docker.io/procustodibus/wireguard:latest inside systemd: setting pull timeout to 5m0s
  Nov 22 21:10:23 proscale-micro-01.abc.abctechnology.com wireguard[1395]: Error: initializing source docker://procustodibus/wireguard:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192>
  Nov 22 21:10:23 proscale-micro-01.abc.abctechnology.com systemd[1]: wireguard.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=125/n/a
  Nov 22 21:10:23 proscale-micro-01.abc.abctechnology.com systemd[1]: wireguard.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Adding 'Requires=network-online.target' to [Unit] fixed it. I was misunderstanding the role of 'After='.